# Replacing 18650 Cells in a laptop Battery

Tags: batteries, laptop

Is it possible to reconstruct a battery of a laptop with better quality 18650 Cells than that are used by the  OEM Manufacturers. eg i have a MSI ge62 6qf with rubbed off LG cells so i cant tell what MAH they are but the battery is designed for 4700-4900mAh. Since i cant buy an OEM battery in my country and it is like impossible to import as a battery will cost 3 times of the said item to import it. So here comes my idea since i have a spot welder in my university and i can buy good quality Panasonic NCR18650B 3400 mAh, can i replace them in the laptop battery

What will be the issues and problems related to the battery Construction except being extra careful in spot welding.
What are also the general concepts related to replacing 18650 Cells
are laptop cells protected like the ones offered in the market or they dont have protection
what is the Role of the controllers in each of battery
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sure thing. This has been done many times. The problem is usually the spot welding and keeping yourself safe while assembling it.

Comment: What is the construction of your battery? Does it have any cells in parallel? Is it 2P3S?

Comment: I got 2p3S in configuration. The battery model is m6H by MSI.